# How do I upload a webpage to Bluemix using the cf CLI?

Tags: cloud-foundry, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to upload an `index.html` page to [Bluemix](https://ace.ng.bluemix.net/) using the [cf CLI](http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/devguide/installcf/whats-new-v6.html). I'm not sure if I'm approaching this with the right mentality. I'm thinking of uploading this HTML file as we usually do with normal hosting services, through FTP. With Bluemix I assume I should be using the `push` command in cf and treat this `index.html` as an app. Is this right?

If this is right, I'm not getting how to use this command. Can you give me an example of full command to push/upload this page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `cf push` command would be the one to use to 'upload' your application to the Bluemix server. However, it does more than just upload. In Bluemix there is a concept of a runtime or buildpack, the idea being this will be the runtime to run your application. So if you uploaded a Java application you would pair it with the Java Liberty Buildpack/runtime. If you uploaded a PHP application then you would pair it with the PHP buildpack.

If you pushed just a HTML file with no buildpack then you would likely get an error indicating the buildpack could not be determined. Bluemix tries to guess the type of buildpack you want based on the type of files uploaded, and then pull the buildpack from an internal cache. The `cf push` command allows you to explicitly state the buildpack to use `-b` so there is no guess work and no need to rely on only the buildpack that Bluemix currently knows about.

In your case, for a static HTML file you would need some type of http server like [nginx](https://blog.starkandwayne.com/2014/08/11/host-static-sites-on-cloud-foundry/) as the 'runtime'. Notice that Bluemix currently does not have a built-in buildpack for this, so you'd have to get it from somewhere else. There are a few buildpacks available already, but the best one to use would be this one: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/staticfile-buildpack . To use it simply supply that url with the `-b` option on the `cf push` command from the root directory of your application i.e.

`cf push yourappname -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/staticfile-buildpack`

- Be sure you are issuing this command from your app directory.
- The `yourappname` will be part of the URL for your website/app

For an actual example, we will upload your `index.html` which exist in folder `C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\projects\ProjectHelloWorld` and we will call this app `HelloWorld`. Here is what we would do:

```
C:\> cd C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\projects\ProjectHelloWorld
C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\projects\ProjectHelloWorld> cf push HelloWorld -b https://git
hub.com/cloudfoundry-community/staticfile-buildpack
```

Bluemix will then upload everything in that local directory to the server and also grab the buildpack from the URL location and stage your application code with the buildpack, Bluemix will then attempt to start the application. This is an example Bluemix output when the `push` command succeed:

```
Creating app HelloWorld in org xyz@gmail.com / space test as xyz@gmail.com...
OK    
Creating route HelloWorld.mybluemix.net...
OK    
Binding HelloWorld.mybluemix.net to HelloWorld...
OK    
Uploading HelloWorld...
Uploading app files from: C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\projects\ProjectHelloWorld
Uploading 1M, 21 files
Done uploading
OK    
Starting app HelloWorld in org xyz@gmail.com / space test as xyz@gmail.com...
-----> Downloaded app package (960K)
    Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/staticfile-buildpack'...
grep: Staticfile: No such file or directory
    -----> Using root folder
-----> Copying project files into public/
-----> Setting up nginx
grep: Staticfile: No such file or directory
-----> Uploading droplet (3.4M)

1 of 1 instances running

App started    

OK
Showing health and status for app HelloWorld in org xyz@gmail.com / space
 test as xyz@gmail.com...
OK    
requested state: started
instances: 1/1
usage: 1G x 1 instances
urls: HelloWorld.mybluemix.net
last uploaded: Tue Nov 25 14:50:44 +0000 2014
```

For more details:

- See the github page for the buildpack on how to structure your application (public folder etc)
- See [Bluemix Docs website](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/?cm_mc_uid=&cm_mc_sid_50200034%7CBLUEMIX#). It has a lot of demos and examples.
- See [Takehiko Amano's Bluemix demo](https://amanoblog.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/create-a-static-web-site-on-ibm-bluemix/). Is a good and easy to understand demo.

Answer (score 2):

you can either deploy your app directly using "cf push ..." or via creating a manifest.yml file.if you create manifest.yml file inside you app code path,only cf push is sufficient.

below is the reference link for this:

```
 http://clouds-with-carl.blogspot.in/2014/02/deploy-minimal-nodejs-application-to.html
```

Hope it clears your doubt!!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as whitfiea mentioned its pretty simple.  You need to use the cf push command.  For example if you had a static website with an index.html file.

For example the following.

```
[02:30 PM] jsloyer@jeffs-mbp [friendme]>ls
index.html
```

To push that app to Bluemix run the following.

```
cf push yourappname -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/staticfile-buildpack.git
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/index.html
In this browse Creating Web Apps->Building a web app-> Uploading an app

It says;-
You can use a sample Java™ web application to get started. This sample application displays the list of environment variables that are available. You can download the sample Java web application from the community sample site. The sample application contains a single JSP and the WEB-INF/web.xml file.

Extract the downloaded file, and a new directory that contains the application is created. From the newly created application directory, issue the cf push command. In the following example, you can use a unique name testEnv for the application and 512M for memory allocation. The name must be unique in the whole Bluemix environment.

$ cf push testEnv -m 512m

->So as per your requirement, you can add your html file along with the JSP file before uploading the application.
Hopefully this help...